# Python Flask HTML Not Showing

Tags: python, html, flask

Im following a flask tutorial from youtube, and I noticed when I run my code, my web application outputs nothing. This only happens when I'm trying to use HTML though.

Below is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Devo Developerr',
        'title': 'Blog Post 1',
        'content': 'First post content',
        'date_posted': 'October 23, 2020'
    },
    {
        'author': 'Jane Doe',
        'title': 'Blog Post 2',
        'content': 'Second post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 21, 2020'
    }
]


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)


@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my main flask file.

This is my HTML file, home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>By {{ post.author }} on {{ post.fate_posted }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    {% end for %} 
</body>
</html>
```

What the aimed output is:[image: Aimed Output]

What the output is right now :[image: Output Right Now]

Comment: where is the template home.html? It needs to be in the templates directory.

Comment: @Nabin It is inside a folder named "templates"

Answer (score 1):

In your Flask project directory create the `templates` directory and move your templates there.

```
mkdir templates
mv *.html templates
```

Flask loads templates from this directory by default, you shouldn't need to configure anything else.

Comment: I already made an folder name "templates". I have home.html inside it. I tried changing the code in what you said. Can you specify the mkdir templates thing a bit more? Thanks

Comment: Flask assumes you have your templates in **templates** dir by default, so if you're in your Flask dir just do `mkdir templates` to create it, if it's not there, and just use it and copy your `about.html` there.

Comment: So, Am i supposed to ender "mkdir templates" into my terminal? And when I do that, I get an error saying saying it already exists. Thanks for helping.